# Is there a way to make a spacing between div's with shadow?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make 3 divs in one row. Divs are divided for two parts, one with image and other with 3 lines of text.

Divs are with box-shadow style.

When I make all of this i get no spacing between div's, when I add extra margin or padding I get problem when page is resized.

This is what I done most close to what I want, only problem is when i resize browser divs collide with selfs.

When I try to make main 3 div's with breakpoints like `col-sm-6-md-4` its crap

I try many ways to do this. This is one of them.. not too nice because with extra padding py-4 and probably this make errors.

I have one working version but with different structure like img is above and text bottom and then its works.

```css
.box1 {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4 py-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col ">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-11 box1 d-flex">
                <div class="box2"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a"></div>
                <div class="box2">
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 py-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col ">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-11 box1 d-flex">
                <div class="box2"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a"></div>
                <div class="box2">
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 py-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col ">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-11 box1 d-flex">
                <div class="box2"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a"></div>
                <div class="box2">
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                  <p>text</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<---- below is working code but with other layout what i dont wont -->


  <---- below is working code but with other layout what i dont wont -->



    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box1">
            <img class="" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box1">
            <img class="" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box1">
            <img class="" src="img/icon/m/img.png" alt="a">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing percentage-based margin and widths?

But if you're using bootstrap the columns should automatically have padding between them.

Something like -

```
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 30%
    margin: 1.66666667%;
}
```

Maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.